# Guardado de datos en cascada en EF6

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, entity-framework-6

Estoy trabajando con EF6 y estoy intentando realizar un guardado de datos en cascada que no logro hacer funcionar (o no lo entiendo). Para poner un ejemplo, digamos que tengo una Entidad **Pedidos** la cual tiene datos como "IdPedido", "NumPedido" etc. y una lista (correspondiente a datos relacionados de otra tabla) como "listaProductos" la cual tiene datos como "IdProducto", "IdPedido"(FK), "NombreProducto" etc.

Para que nos entendamos el "paquete" va con todos los datos, va hasta _unitOfWork.pedidosRepository.Add(pedidos) o _unitOfWork.pedidosRepository.Update(pedidos), pasando al final por context.SaveChanges(); sin ningun problema, pero resulta que realmente guarda únicamente los datos de la tabla **pedidos** y no los de la tabla relacionada **productos**.

Se que suele ser recomendable añadir código para resolver la duda mas fácilmente, pero en este caso creo que es irrelevante, ya que lo que me gustaría saber es si hay alguna configuración que me he podido saltar para que realice el guardado en cascada (la tabla principal + secundaria), si en realidad es algo que hay que hacer por separado (guardar tabla por tabla) o por defecto algún sitio en el que pueda ver como funciona esto.

He estado buscando por Google y me ha sido imposible encontrar ninguna explicación de como se hace el guardado de datos en cascada.

un saludo y gracias de antemano.

EDIT: Añado código de las entidades Pedido y producto.

***Pedido.cs***

```
namespace Domain.Entities
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Pedido
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Pedido()
        {
            this.ProductoPedidos = new HashSet<ProductoPedido>();

//Mas Elementos

        }

        public long IdPedidos { get; set; }
        public long NumPedido { get; set; }
        public string DescPedido { get; set; }

//Mas Elementos      

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ProductoPedido> ProductoPedidos{ get; set; }  

//Mas Elementos      
    }
}
```

***Producto.cs***

```
namespace Domain.Entities
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Producto
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Producto()
        {
            //Mas Elementos
        }

        public long IdProducto { get; set; }
        public long IdPedido { get; set; }        
        public string NombreProducto { get; set; }

//Mas Elementos

        public virtual Pedido Pedido  { get; set; }

//Mas Elementos

    }
}
```

EDIT 2: Añado Código de guardado/inserción

***PedidoController.cs***

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Guardar un Pedido
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pedidoCE">Pedido a guardar</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Route("api/pedido/guardarPedido")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult GuardarPedido([FromBody]PedidoCE pedidoCE)
        {
         try
            {
                PedidoService servicio = new PedidoService();
                Pedido pedido = Mapper.Map<PedidoCE, Pedido>(pedidoCE);

                Pedido pedidoGuardado = servicio.SavePedido(pedido);

                return Ok(new { success = true, idPedido = pedidoGuardado.IdPedido });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TraceManager.LogError(ex);
                //return InternalServerError(ex);
                return Ok(new { success = false });
            }
        }
```

***PedidoService.cs***

```
public Pedido SavePedido(Pedido pedido)
        {
            Pedido pedidoGuardado = pedido;

            string username = SessionHelper.GetUsername();
            pedido.ModificadoPor = username;
            pedido.FechaModificacion = DateTime.Now;


            if (pedido.IdPedido == 0)
            {
                pedido.CreadoPor = username;
                pedido.FechaCreacion = DateTime.Now;
                pedidoGuardado = _unitOfWork.PedidoRepository.Add(pedido);
            }
            else
            {
                _unitOfWork.PedidoRepository.Update(pedido);
            }
            _unitOfWork.Commit(); 

            return pedidoGuardado;
        }
```

luego, el Add y el Update, son algo genérico como:

```
     /// <summary>
     /// Add an element to collection
     /// </summary>
     /// <typeparam name="TEntity">Entity type</typeparam>
     /// <param name="entity">Element to add</param>
     public virtual TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
     {
         TEntity addedEntity = _context.Set<TEntity>().Add((TEntity)entity);
         //Commit();
         return addedEntity;
     }

     /// <summary>
     /// Updates an element
     /// </summary>
     /// <param name="entity">Element to update</param>
     public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
     {
         _context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
         _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
     }
```

El Commit usa un context.SaveChanges() de UnitOfWork sin mas complicación.

Espero que con esto sea suficiente para identificar el problema.

un saludo.

Comment: Indica por favor el código de los Modelos Pedidos y Productos, para ver cómo tienes configuradas las relaciones EF.

Comment: Tal y como te comenta Rafael, sería bueno ver las entidades configuradas y además, sería bueno ver como estás añadiendo los pedidos al objeto de repositorio de pedidos. Si tiene alguna llave foranea, debe de llevarla. Si la llave primaria es auto incrementable, el valor debe der ir nulo. Si estás utilizando una web api. Deberías de tener acceso a la consola para ver las instrucciones que se están ejecutando. y ver en donde se está quedando. Comparte esas partes del código y tal vez podamos revisar más a detalle.

Comment: ya he añadido como pedisteis el código de las entidades. Espero que con esto sea suficiente, de lo contrario comentarmelo. (He recortado el código quitando otros campos o relaciones irrelevantes ya que con esto se ve perfectamente como esta estructurado)

Comment: ¿Sería mucho pedir que agreges la parte de tu código donde realizas la grabación/guardado/inserción de los datos?

Comment: Creo que he añadido ya todo el codigo del recorrido en el Backend para el guardado de datos. Espero que con esto ya sea suficiente.